# SymmetricDS - Add node id on transformation

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

I have multiple DBs replicating to a single Master DB, and I have a table with the table ID that I use for other purposes as well, I would like to add a column from this table which contain the DB identification on every line that is replicated on my master DB.
Is it possible? All the tests I made ended up doing nothing.

Comment: So you want to add a source_id column to the master table and make it a composite primary key and populate that from the source dbs?  If so, then yes a transform will do that.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible because of the nature of transformations. They're defined over a group of nodes. Assuming all client nodes belong to the same group they'll be sharing one transformation definition.

Let's take another approach. Each client node is uniquely identifies with its external ID. Use it as a prefix if the ID table on every client and synchronize it freely to the master without worrying that it will overlap with any other.

If the application is legacy and can't be changed to accommodate the prefix use writer filters on master side that will be intercepting data coming from client nodes adding a prefix equal to client's external ID to each update to the ID table. On client's side add a writer filter that will be stripping down the prefix. You can use the prefix on the master to route rows only to clients they've been sent from.

There's another answer that explains database writer filters in details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389635/32090

Answer (score 0):

That is possible using a "variable" transform.  Here is an example where "store" replicates to "corp" and dynamically adds a "source_node_id" column.

```
INSERT INTO SYM_TRANSFORM_TABLE (TRANSFORM_ID, SOURCE_NODE_GROUP_ID, TARGET_NODE_GROUP_ID, TRANSFORM_POINT, SOURCE_TABLE_NAME, TARGET_TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_POLICY, DELETE_ACTION) 
VALUES ('item', 'corp', 'store', 'EXTRACT', 'item', 'item', 'IMPLIED', 'DEL_ROW');

INSERT INTO SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN (TRANSFORM_ID, INCLUDE_ON, TARGET_COLUMN_NAME, SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME, PK, TRANSFORM_TYPE, TRANSFORM_EXPRESSION, TRANSFORM_ORDER) 
VALUES ('item', '*', 'ITEM_ID', 'ITEM_ID', 1, 'copy', null, 1);

INSERT INTO SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN (TRANSFORM_ID, INCLUDE_ON, TARGET_COLUMN_NAME, SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME, PK, TRANSFORM_TYPE, TRANSFORM_EXPRESSION, TRANSFORM_ORDER) 
VALUES ('item', '*', 'SOURCE_NODE_ID', null, 1, 'variable', 'source_node_id', 2);
```

Comment: Trying this but cant make it work, it always replicate the entire table and does not add the SOURCE_NODE_ID
I'm also limited on sending data always store -> corp, there is no database corp -> store